# Finding a value from a probability density function

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

I've been asked the following based on a probability course I'm taking :

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
cx^3(1-x)^2 & 0 \le x \le 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

where $x$ has a beta distribution with probability density function.

Find $c$

My solution :

Step 1
$$ 
1 = \int_0^1 cx^3(1-x^2)dx
$$

Step 2
$$
1 = c\int_0^1 x^3(1-x)^2dx
$$

Step 3
$$
1 = c\int_0^1 x^3-x^5 dx
$$

As
$$
\int x^ndx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
$$

Therefore :

Step 4
$$
c \Big[ \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{x^6}{6} \Big]^1_0
$$

My solution is based on my notes but I'm unsure how to arrive at step 4 from step 3. Specifically how the integral symbol is removed and arrive at square brackets with 1 & 0 : $ \Big]^1_0$

How should c be solved from $c\Big[ \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{x^6}{6} \Big]^1_0 $  ?

Update :

## $c\Big[ \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{x^6}{6} \Big]^1_0 $

$\frac{1^4}{4} - 0 = \frac{1}{4}$

$c = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Just checking, are you asking the right question? $a$ doesn't appear in the original question isn't it?

Comment: Also $x^{3}$ in the definition of $f$ has suddenly become $x$ in your argument.

Comment: Recall $\int f +g dx = \int f dx + \int g dx$.

Comment: Recall also $x=y \times z \to y= \frac{x}{z}$

Comment: Your "step 4" is wrong (probably a typo).  It should be $c\left[\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^4}{4}\right]_0^1= 1$.  Evaluating $c\left[\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^4}{4}\right]_0^1$ gives $c\left(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{4}\right)= \frac{c}{4}= 1$

Comment: @user247327 thanks, now corrected. How are functions with notation $\Big]^{n_1}_{n_0}$ evaluated ? Is there a name for this type of evaluation ?

Comment: The distribution is supposed to be $\text{Beta}(4,3)$. So $c$ is of course $1/B(4,3)$, which is simplified using the Gamma function.

Comment: "$\left[f(x)\right]_a^b$ **means** f(b)- f(a).

Comment: Have you ever tried evaluating a definite integral before? What is the notation used in your text?

Comment: You incorrectly go from $(1-x)^2$ to $(1-x^2)$ in Step 1

Comment: @user121049 thank you, ive updated question and provided answer.

Comment: Step 2 is now correct but typo still in Step 1. But more importantly $[\frac{x^4}{4}- \frac{x^6}{6}]^1_0=(\frac{1}{4}- \frac{1}{6}) - (\frac{0}{4}- \frac{0}{6}) =1/12$.  So $c/12=1$

Comment: @blue-sky `How should c be solved from` $c\Big[ \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{x^6}{6} \Big]^1_0 $`?`  Not at all since it is not an equality. The equality is $c\Big[ \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{x^6}{6} \Big]^1_0 =1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea that the PDF must integrate to 1, by definition. This gives: $\int_0^1 c x^3 (1-x)^2 dx = 1$, implying $\int_0^1 c x^3(1+x^2-2x) dx = 1$.

Using the general rule $\int_0^1 x^n dx = 1/(n+1)$, you get:

$c(1/4 + 1/6 - 2/5) = 1$, i.e. $ c = 60$.